# How to know which radio button is selected on a view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a created a list view for one of my controller's index action.
I have added a new column "Select This" to this list view, by using the view's source.
The column will contain radio button for each entry in the list. This i have achieved by just placing a radio button control from tool box in the "Select This" column. This i have done in the design of the view and when i run it, i get radio buttons, one for each of the entry. The page also has a link button and i want to call a controller action on this link button click which will receive the index of radio button selected. So if i select 5th radio button, how can receive 5 in the controller action.

How can i do this?

Regards,
kapil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you used plain HTML, your radio buttons will all have the same name, but different value. You will get one result in the POST, which will contain the selected value.

If you used ASP.net helpers, it's the same, but they will be generated for you: see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410596.aspx You will pass the same name (first parameter) and different values for each input (second parameter).

Comment: How can i know that - which radio button is clicked on View itself sothat i can send the selected radio's ID from the link button click present on the view?

Comment: What does it men to send radio IDs? Where are you sending them? What do you mean by "link button"? Try to explain more clearly, and open a new question for this.